# Does anyone know if it's possible to get the new dictation languages from Yosemite into Mavericks?

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

The question really says it all. I'm especially interested in getting Dutch as a possibility in Mavericks, because I am Dutch.

Comment: Did you download Dutch in Yosemite?

Comment: Uh, yes, and no. As in, the language was in the list of the available languages for dictation. I didn't do anything special to put it in that list, it was just there. And then I checked it so the system would download the language so it's also available for offline use. Why? Do you think I could find that language pack and then send it to my mavericks system and install it there manually?

Comment: Try to isolate the file in this folder /System/Library/Speech/Recognizers/ and copy it from there in to Mavericks, I do not know if it will work.